# How can you use ArchiMate together with TOGAF ADM?

Tags: enterprise-architect, togaf, archimate

Can TOGAF Architecture Method (ADM) be seamlessly integrated with ArchiMate. Are there any tools out there in the market that supports this kind of integration and modeling authoring process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely possible! And in fact, there are some examples around and people in the industry are already practising it this way!

**Information from the Open Group**

TOGAF ADM can be well integrated with ArchiMate and, in fact, that was one of the reason why ArchiMate designed for. [Open Group](http://www.opengroup.org/) has an article about the feasibility of [TOGAF ADM and ArchiMate integration](https://blog.opengroup.org/2015/02/17/using-the-archimate-language-to-model-togaf-architectures/)

**Example from Software Vendor**

Such kind of implementation from the Software Vendor – Visual Paradigm also illustrated this by integrating the two open standards TOGAF ADM and ArchiMate 3 into one unified software platform.

Here is an article for how to: [Use ArchiMate tool with TOGAF ADM](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/archimate/using-archimate-tool-with-togaf-adm/) seamlessly by using the Guide-Through Process.  The screenshots captured from the software are illustrated as follows:
[image] 
(Source: [TOGAF Guide-Through Process illustration](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/tour/enterprise-architecture/enterprise-architecture-and-guide-through-process.jsp))

Answer (score 1):

There is open source [Archi](https://www.archimatetool.com/) ArchiMate tool based on Eclipse. Also the are [Sample Models](https://github.com/archimatetool/ArchiModels) you can start with.

Answer (score 0):

We've Used Sparx Enterprise Architect to model TOGAF ADM with ArchiMate. Each of the ArchiMate Viewpoints can be implemented using Sparx EA, and interleaved in TOGAF ADM.

This could be setup specifically for your Domain / Project, or you can embark on a generic Template and start modeling.

An off-the-shelf integration is available from Biner (http://www.beasisoftware.com/)